# Regex nested structure with special charaters

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, parsing

I need to find a Regex in C# that is matching and returning strings from a nested structre delimited by $( and )$.

My input string is:

`$(string1$(string2)$sometexthere$(string3$(string4)$texttext)$anothertext)$`

The output must be :

```
$(string1$(string2)$sometexthere$(string3$(string4)$texttext)$anothertext)$
$(string2)$
$(string3$(string4)$texttext)$
$(string4)$
```

I have tried with this regex `\$\([^\$]*\)\$` but it's only returning the most inner `string2` and `string4`.

Is there a solution to return each match with regex ? or even through a loop ? ( `$(` and `)$` can be replaced after by `[` and `]` )

Comment: No, regexps can't suitably capture arbitrary nesting. You could use regexps for $( and )$ to split, i.e. tokenize the string, then process it into a tree.

Comment: I don't think the backslash is needed inside the square brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
(?=(?<result>\$\((?>[^()]+|(?<o>\()|(?<-o>\)))*(?(o)(?!))\)\$))
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3D%28%3F%3Cresult%3E%5C%24%5C%28%28%3F%3E%5B%5E%28%29%5D%2B%7C%28%3F%3Co%3E%5C%28%29%7C%28%3F%3C-o%3E%5C%29%29%29*%28%3F%28o%29%28%3F!%29%29%5C%29%5C%24%29%29&i=%24%28string1%24%28string2%29%24sometexthere%24%28string3%24%28string4%29%24texttext%29%24anothertext%29%24&o=x), grab each `match.Groups["result"].Value`.

[image]

C# code snippet:

```
var pattern = @"(?=(?<result>\$\((?>[^()]+|(?<o>\()|(?<-o>\)))*(?(o)(?!))\)\$))";
var results = Regex.Matches(text, pattern)
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(x => x.Groups["result"].Value)
        .ToList();
```

See the [C# demo online](https://ideone.com/XL10Qo).

**Pattern details**

- `(?=` - a positive lookahead that will enable overlapping matches:

  - `(?<result>\$\((?>[^()]+|(?<o>\()|(?<-o>\)))*(?(o)(?!))\)\$)` - Group "result":

    - `\$\(` - `$(` substring
    - `(?>[^()]+|(?<o>\()|(?<-o>\)))*` - 1+ chars other than `(` and `)` or a `(` pushed on to the "o" group stack or `)` popped from the "o" group stack, 0 or more times
    - `(?(o)(?!))` - a conditional that fails the match if Group "o" stack is not empty
    - `\)\$` - a `)$` substring
- `)` - end of the lookahead